# Android Studio: Is it possible to define library module manifest placeholders in main module?

Tags: android, android-studio, merge, android-manifest, placeholder

I'm adding some components to a library module manifest file. Apparently it is possible  to use the `${applicationId}` placeholder even though I have not declared it in the library's build.gradle file. The only place it is declared is in the main module's build.gradle.

So I though if I added a custom placeholder to the main module it would also work.

In short: this seems to work:

Library's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="${applicationId}.LibraryActivity" ...>
```

Main module's build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {applicationId "package.name.here"...
```

But this does not:

Library's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="${customPlaceholder} ...>
```

Main module's build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {manifestPlaceholders = [customPlaceholder:"Foo"] ...}
```

Is there a reason one works but not the other?

Comment: Did you find some way to achieve this? I have the same scenario as yours.

Comment: I have something similar but not exactly the same. My library module is having a Launcher activity which I want to replace with the one in the Main app's Manifest. Is there a way to manage that as well? I can't edit the Main app as it has different vendor. I am just a module which it uses as a dependency. Manifest Merger doesn't work as Lib has lower priority.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes! We can do it!

Just add the code to library's `build.gradle`:

```
    manifestPlaceholders = [
            customPlaceholder: '${customPlaceholder}'
    ]
```

Or in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
manifestPlaceholders["customPlaceholder"] = "\${customPlaceholder}"
```

Comment: Make sure you use `'${customPlaceholder}'` instead of `"${customPlaceholder}"` took me 1h

Comment: If using build.gradle.kts it is:
`manifestPlaceholders["customPlaceholder"] = "\${customPlaceholder}"`

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this answer. The value is surrounded by single quotes and it was my understanding that single quotes should only be used for direct strings, right? I get the impression this 'works' for the wrong reasons.

Comment: The correct way is using double quote.

Comment: @ClausHolst Thanks for the info, this was so hard to find lol